# Having problems losing jQuery focus "onkeypress" from document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a website where I need to store key events.

I have been doing this via

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
```

Then I am having this data and printing onto the body as is.

```
$('body').html($('body').html() + ' evt.key);
```

This does works until i start typing into a textbox or textarea.

I have to make jQuery lose it's focus from body whenever I click anywhere on the form.

Thanks for the answers :)

EDIT

Thanks for Xufox and Santi's answers, I have fixed my issue by taking onkeypress action to a body container `<div id="container">` and then printing the textboxes to out of container.

Comment: You replace the entire HTML inside `<body>` with this line of code. It seems, you just append something, so append it to another element without rewriting its HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as Xufox mentioned in the comments, you're rewriting the entire `<body>` of your document each time a key is pressed.

That `<body>` includes the textbox/textareas/etc, and so by rewriting the body, you're actually deleting and re-creating those textboxes each time.

The resolution would be to list the keypresses somewhere else, rather than rewriting the entire `<body>` element each time. In the example below, I've created a `<div>` called "pressedKeys", which I use to store the keypresses.

Instead of rewriting the content the entire `<body>`, we're just rewriting the contents of one `<div>`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type here"><br>
<div id="pressedKeys"></div>
```

```
var $pressedKeys = $("#pressedKeys");

document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    $pressedKeys.html($pressedKeys.html() + evt.key);
}
```

[**Example JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u10mukxk/2/)

Comment: This does work great! Though, I am rewriting the entire <body> in order to add the textbox. I am checking the user input after user inputted enter key. If it corresponds one of the predefined words, I am rewriting the form itself. What shall i do in order to avoid this?

Comment: In your implementation, can you add/remove elements from the form based on user input, instead of rewriting it from scratch each time? Or, can you rewrite the body only when the enter key is pressed?

Comment: `else if(cmd == "contact") $('body').html($('body').html() + '<br><div id="contact"><center>Contact Form<br><form><input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="name"><br><br><input type="text" placeholder="Your E-Mail" name="mail"><br><br><textarea name="comment" form="usrform" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea><br><input value="Send" type="submit"></form> ');` After checking the user input, i am printing the contact form like this.

Comment: Please, rather than trying to figure this out in the comments, post the *entire* section of your code that isn't working in the question itself. I've answered the question you asked - It seems now that your question is way bigger than what you've chosen to disclose, however.